# Toggle an Image on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle an image on Click. It's partially working but also partially not **:'(**
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/4/.

When I click the large image, the smaller image changes (from 50x50 to 151x151) - *hurrah!*

But when I click the 'Read more' text, the small image remains the same image. **The small, nested image needs to change when I click the 'Read more' text.**

Can anyone show me how I can resolve this?

I've attached my **jQuery**:

```
$(function(){
        // The height of the content block when it's not expanded
        var adjustheight = 130;
        // The "more" link text
        var moreText = "Click to read more...";
        // The "less" link text
        var lessText = "Click to read less...";
        // Sets the .more-block div to the specified height and hides any content that overflows
        $(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        // The section added to the bottom of the "more-less" div
        $(".more-less").append('<p style="display:block;margin-top:8px"><a href="#" class="adjust"></a></p>');
        $("a.adjust").text(moreText);
        $(".adjust").toggle(function() {
                $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
                // Hide the [...] when expanded
                $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
                $(this).text(lessText);
            }, function() {
                $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
                $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
                $(this).text(moreText);
        });
        });

        $(function(){
            $('img').click(function(){
                $(this).closest('article').find('.adjust').click();
            });
        });

        $(function(){ 
           $("article").click(function(){ 
           $("img.small").attr('src',  
                        ($("img.small").attr('src') == 'http://placehold.it/50x50'  
                    ? 'http://placehold.it/151x151'  
                    : 'http://placehold.it/50x50' 
                             ) 
                        )  
            }); 
        });
```

and my **HTML**:

```
<article id="post-5" >

            <div class="more-less">    
                <div class="more-block">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed diam purus, lacinia eget placerat sit amet, bibendum nec nisl. Curabitur a mattis ipsum. Praesent quis nisi in purus malesuada rhoncus. Pellentesque ut quam eget libero congue lobortis. Nunc sed quam ac erat lobortis eleifend. Donec elementum sodales cursus. Aliquam porttitor massa nisi, in laoreet turpis. Sed consequat condimentum lorem ut dignissim. Sed hendrerit mauris ut massa fermentum laoreet. Pellentesque a leo vitae enim dictum lobortis. Praesent commodo feugiat velit iaculis malesuada.</p>
                    <p>Praesent sem lectus, ullamcorper eget ullamcorper a, congue vel nisl. Nullam volutpat leo vel dui venenatis dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac scelerisque lorem. Ut blandit magna eu turpis posuere gravida. Fusce egestas risus in libero ullamcorper sagittis. Vestibulum molestie metus vitae quam dignissim consequat. Vivamus id tellus id lorem consectetur iaculis sit amet interdum ante. Quisque lacinia tellus id mi tincidunt fermentum dignissim velit laoreet. Quisque scelerisque nunc iaculis nisi varius ultrices.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus id elit ac lacus faucibus ullamcorper. Etiam ullamcorper pretium tellus, ut pharetra ante pulvinar vel. Sed neque diam, semper vel rhoncus non, congue ut sapien. Integer a mi eget libero elementum lobortis. Donec hendrerit egestas ligula sit amet eleifend. Curabitur pharetra venenatis tempor. Quisque pulvinar malesuada justo, ut euismod arcu pharetra vitae. Cras lobortis, ligula id euismod euismod, ipsum risus varius urna, faucibus gravida lectus mi nec nulla. Fusce eleifend fringilla nibh ut vulputate. Vivamus sagittis leo metus. Etiam facilisis convallis lacus adipiscing hendrerit. Duis ultricies euismod libero, nec blandit est semper a. Phasellus sit amet justo sed quam elementum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="small" style="position:absolute;margin-left: 240px;margin-top: 127px;" />
                <a href="#" title="News Item 1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x187" alt="News Item 1" width="300" height="187" /></a>
            </p>            

        </article>
```

**Many thanks for any pointers.**

Comment: Can you please explain the functionality in more detail, I'm unable to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Apologies. Basically I want to click the 'Click to read more' text and the "small" image (http://placehold.it/50x50) then changes to http://placehold.it/151x151. If you try the Demo, you'll see it works when I click the BIG image, but not when I click 'Read more' text. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why can't I see any small images (`50x50`) on fiddle, I can just see sizes `300x187` and `151x151`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I really should have changed the colour :-) No need for any eye tests for you ;-D

Comment: Hey did `jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/7` work?

Comment: So sorry for my delay, long story. It works beautifully!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Oh, and feel free to create an answer linking to it and I'll accept - again, super sorry for my delayed reply. Out of my control I'm afraid. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Sure, no problems :) I'll update my answer accordingly ! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I have understood you correctly, all you've got to do is,

Change this

```
$("article").click(function() {
        //your code here
    });
```

to,

```
$("article, .adjust").click(function() {
        //your code here
    });
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/5/)

**EDIT:**

Changed a couple of things to match what you needed,

1) Change this,

```
$(this).parents('article').find('.adjust').click();
```

to,

```
$(this).parents('article').find('.adjust').trigger('click');
```

as the latter is a proper way to trigger an event.

2) Change in the image swap function,

```
$("article, .adjust").click(function() {
    /*Save references in variables*/
    var imgToSwap = $(this).parents("article").find("img.small");
    var img_small = 'http://placehold.it/50x50';
    var img_large = 'http://placehold.it/151x151';

    imgToSwap.attr('src', (imgToSwap.attr('src') ==  img_small ? img_large : img_small));
});
```

Using `$(this)` will help you get the image in the right context.

Check the [fiddle test here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/8/)

Comment: That's almost right, but I also need the large image link to work still. So clicking 'Read more' & also clicking BIG image both make the smallest image bigger. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, and it should only affect ONE of the `<article>`s :-)

Comment: So, right now, if I hit `read more`, `50x50` changes to `151x151`, but now if I hit `300x187` it should still change to `50x50`, right?

Comment: Click `read more` or `300x187` changes `50x50` to `151x151` | Click `read less` or `300x187` changes `151x151` to `50x50`. It should only happen to one `<article>` at a time. My apologies for any confusion here.

Comment: Almost perfect! Only slight issue: If you click 1st `<article>` read more then click 2nd `<article>` read more, it seems to confuse the script :-/ Can you try?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21092/discussion-between-badzoke-and-michaelmcgurk)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a few problems here.  I don't see that you've applied the `adjust` class to any element in your HTML.  I also see that CSS is applied directly in JavaScript. (Why not use a .css file?)

This part of the code looks very nice:

```
$("img.small").attr('src',  
    ($("img.small").attr('src') == 'http://placehold.it/50x50'  
    ? 'http://placehold.it/151x151'  
    : 'http://placehold.it/50x50' ))
```

This is good use of the ternary operator.

My I suggest that you use this code as the click handler on `a.adjust`, assuming that the link that expands the image is supposed to be decorated with the `adjust` class?

```
var changeImage = function() {
    $("img.small").attr('src',  
    ($("img.small").attr('src') == 'http://placehold.it/50x50'  
    ? 'http://placehold.it/151x151'  
    : 'http://placehold.it/50x50' ))
});
$('a.adjust').click(changeImage);
$('article').click(changeImage);
```

I hope this helps.  If the question were written more precisely, it might be helpful.